# UISplitViewController in a TabBar ios6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am aware that Apple have previously stated that UISplitView controllers should not be used within a TabBarController by reading through other posts on stackoverflow - I had a look at the relevant documentation on this in the Apple developer site, but I couldn't find anything to suggest this shouldn't be done.

I know that in previous versions it was due to the fact that the SplitViewController did not properly receive the orientation messages - however my app is always in landscape mode.

I have 9 split view controllers - and if I had to change this now it would be a major re-design for my app - infact I am not too sure of another way of displaying the data in a format I require!

Does anyone have any experience of this situation being accepted by Apple in an app recently? I am just concerned as there are so many posts (from 2010 onwards) saying this must never be done, but when looking at the SDK documentation I can't see why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UISplitViewController itself is not allowed to be included in navigation controller or tabbarcontroller. I used the MGSplitViewController, from [MGSplitViewController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mgsplitviewcontroller), however I haven't submitted it to Apple Store yet.
MGSplitViewController is of class UIViewController so you get to include it in a tab bar.